# Confuse something for something else?

Tags: prepositions

In the movie Birddman (2014), Sylvia blames Birdman,

> "It's what you always do. You confuse love for admiration."

Shouldn't it be *confuse love **with** admiration*? Is the meaning the same as confuse with and is it common usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In American English, *confuse for* is sometimes used, but *confuse with* is much more common.  In the [*Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)*](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=62417316), I found the following result counts:

```
 be confused with    766 results
 be confused for     21 results
```

You can do similar searches for the active form `confuse * with|for`, and *with* is overwhelmingly more common in that case as well.  Regardless, *for* is a well-established alternative in standard American English.  *Confuse with* is more common in all registers, but especially in casual speech, *confuse with* is the usual choice.

In British English, *confuse for* is not commonly used.  When I search the [British National Corpus](https://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=62417310), I find the following results:

```
 be confused with    197 results
 be confused for     0 results
```

This seems to confirm that *confuse for* is not generally used in British English.

Most dictionaries only mention *confuse with*.  One that mentions both *confuse with* and *confuse for* is the Oxford Collocations Dictionary for students of English, 2nd ed. (2009), which lists *confuse for* as American English:

> **for** *(esp. AmE)*
>   　*The condition can sometimes be confused for influenza.*
>
> **with**
>   　*I sometimes confuse Jane with her sister.*

As an English language learner, you might want to stick to *confuse with* in your own speech, especially if you're learning British English specifically, but you should be able to understand *confuse for* as well if you come across it.

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive way of thinking about it:

- con[fuse] with, like you would say fuse with
- mis[take] for, as you would say take for granted, take for a fool, etc.